# Embedded - IRQ in SDIO

Tags: embedded

In the [SDIO Card Specification](https://www.sdcard.org/developers/overview/sdio/sdio_spec/Simplified_SDIO_Card_Spec.pdf) in Section 8.1.2, it is mentionedthat the DAT1 pin can act as IRQ as well in the 4-bit SD mode. What is the purpose of IRQ in the SDIO module?

Answer (score 3):

IRQ is a way for the SDIO card to attract the attention of the host, by requesting an interrupt on the host - typically this will make some code run on the host, presumably in the host SDIO card driver.

By using interrupts, the host does not have to continually check the status of the SDIO card waiting for a particular condition, instead the SDIO card will be designed to raise an IRQ when that condition occurs.

Usually the SDIO card will provide a way to enable/disable interrupt requests, probably in one of the SDIO card registers. Once  the  host  has  serviced  the interrupt, it is cleared via some function unique I/O operation from the host to the SDIO card.

The specific meaning of a particular interrupt request will depend completely on the particular card and driver, but for example if the SDIO card is receiving signals from an external device, the IRQ might signal that data is available. Or if the SDIO card is outputting data which is loaded (say) 16 bytes at a time from the host, the IRQ might indicate that the SDIO card can accept a further 16 bytes.

Typically in the host interrupt service routine the host will check the status of the card to determine the reason for the interrupt and then branch to code specific to that reason.

None of this is specific to SDIO - the same principles of using interrupts apply completely to any situation where I/O operations need to occur asynchronously from whatever else the host is doing.